# How to wipe dist/ directory before a build with Parcel

Tags: parceljs

I have a very simple project set up to use Parcel as the bundler. It's just the basic example from their [Getting Started](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html#%F0%9F%9A%80-getting-started) guide.

For a single build everything works fine but I noticed that for every build the javascript code is compiled under a new hash. This can result in multiple JS hashes being created in the `dist/` directory. Is there a way to clear everything from `dist/` before every build so that it only contains the latest code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option that requires little setup and is cross-platform would be to use a plugin like [parcel-plugin-nuke-dist](https://github.com/RadValentin/parcel-plugin-nuke-dist). Just install it and it will clear the `dist/` dir before every build:

```
npm install parcel-plugin-nuke-dist --save-dev
```

NOTE: `parcel-plugin-nuke-dist` isn't compatible with Parcel v2, please see the other answers for alternatives

Answer (score 13):

You can delegate the clean up task to a singular script which task will be to wipe your **output** directory. Please note that using `rm -rf` is more error-prone than using a platform-agnostic package such as **rimraf** which will also executes without any issues in a Windows environment.

The steps are:

1. `npm i -D rimraf`
2. Then edit your package.json **scripts** key like shown below.

```json
{ 
   "scripts": {
     "clean:output": "rimraf dist",
     "start": "npm run clean:output && parcel src/index.html",
     "build": "npm run clean:output && parcel build src/index.html",
  }
 
}
```

As an alterative, you can use a prescript for each of the scripts but I personally think it will make your scripts section hard to read. This approach is more flexible to changes. If you later decide to change the target output directory there is only one place you need to visit and change in the package.json file.

Answer (score 12):

You can run `rm -rf public/dist/*` before running parcel build directly in `package.json` [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts)

```
{ 
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf public/dist/* && parcel build src/index.html --out-dir public/dist --public-url /dist/",
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: For windows, you can substitute `rm -rf` with the great `rimraf` npm module after installing it as a dev dependency.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `rm -rf dist` (or `rimraf`) into a `package.json` script named `prebuild`. This will make it run automatically before building, so you don't have to alter your existing `build` script.

```json
{
   "scripts": {
     "prebuild": "rm -rf dist",
     "build": "parcel build",
  }
}
```